# Saving date to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to send the following to the DB:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_games (team1_ID, team2_ID, game_date) VALUES ('$game1_team1','$game1_team2','$game1_date')";
```

It executes fine, and inserts a row into the table, but the game_date field shows up as value 0000-00-00.

The HTML on my form is:

```
<select name="game1_date"><option value="2013-08-22">Thursday, 22 Aug 2013</option><option value="2013-08-23">Friday, 23 Aug 2013</option><option value="2013-08-24">Saturday, 24 Aug 2013</option><option value="2013-08-25">Sunday, 25 Aug 2013</option><option value="2013-08-26">Monday, 26 Aug 2013</option><option value="2013-08-27">Tuesday, 27 Aug 2013</option><option value="2013-08-28">Wednesday, 28 Aug 2013</option><option value="2013-08-29">Thursday, 29 Aug 2013</option><option value="2013-08-30">Friday, 30 Aug 2013</option><option value="2013-08-31">Saturday, 31 Aug 2013</option><option value="2013-09-01">Sunday, 01 Sep 2013</option><option value="2013-09-02">Monday, 02 Sep 2013</option><option value="2013-09-03">Tuesday, 03 Sep 2013</option><option value="2013-09-04">Wednesday, 04 Sep 2013</option></select>
```

The list of options is generated by the following PHP code:

```
    $myHTMLdate = '';
for($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i ++){
  $startdate = strtotime("today + $i day");
      $myHTMLdate .= '<option value="'.date('Y-m-d', $startdate).'">'.date('l', $startdate).', '.date('d M Y', $startdate).'</option>';
}
```

These things work fine on their own, so why isn't the value being stored correctly by the DB. I read that MySQL stores dates as Y-m-d which is how the value of game1_date is being formatted.

Any ideas here? I'm stuck!

Comment: What is the value of `$game1_date` just before constructing the query?

Comment: try `var_dump($game1_date);` just before the `INSERT`query. And what column type is `game_date`? (date, datetime, timestamp)

Comment: Both $game1_date and $_REQUEST['game1_date'] are returning NULL when I var_dump them. Is there any reason it would do this?